# Include functions file in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CI but would like to include the code below (which sits in a file called color.php) within a view and reference the functions. But doesn't seem to work when I do this per normal php include `include('/assets/color.php');` I've also tried adding `color.php` as a helper and loading it in the view but again not working … Any help on how best to include this would be great.

```
class GetMostCommonColors
{
    var $PREVIEW_WIDTH    = 150;
    var $PREVIEW_HEIGHT   = 150;

    var $error;

    /**
     * Returns the colors of the image in an array, ordered in descending order, where the keys are the colors, and the values are the count of the color.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function Get_Color( $img, $count=20, $reduce_brightness=true, $reduce_gradients=true, $delta=16 )
    {
        if (is_readable( $img ))
        {
            if ( $delta > 2 )
            {
                $half_delta = $delta / 2 - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $half_delta = 0;
            }
            // WE HAVE TO RESIZE THE IMAGE, BECAUSE WE ONLY NEED THE MOST SIGNIFICANT COLORS.
            $size = GetImageSize($img);
            $scale = 1;
            if ($size[0]>0)
            $scale = min($this->PREVIEW_WIDTH/$size[0], $this->PREVIEW_HEIGHT/$size[1]);
            if ($scale < 1)
            {
                $width = floor($scale*$size[0]);
                $height = floor($scale*$size[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                $width = $size[0];
                $height = $size[1];
            }
            $image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
            if ($size[2] == 1)
            $image_orig = imagecreatefromgif($img);
            if ($size[2] == 2)
            $image_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
            if ($size[2] == 3)
            $image_orig = imagecreatefrompng($img);
            // WE NEED NEAREST NEIGHBOR RESIZING, BECAUSE IT DOESN'T ALTER THE COLORS
            imagecopyresampled($image_resized, $image_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1]);
            $im = $image_resized;
            $imgWidth = imagesx($im);
            $imgHeight = imagesy($im);
            $total_pixel_count = 0;
            for ($y=0; $y < $imgHeight; $y++)
            {
                for ($x=0; $x < $imgWidth; $x++)
                {
                    $total_pixel_count++;
                    $index = imagecolorat($im,$x,$y);
                    $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im,$index);
                    // ROUND THE COLORS, TO REDUCE THE NUMBER OF DUPLICATE COLORS
                    if ( $delta > 1 )
                    {
                        $colors['red'] = intval((($colors['red'])+$half_delta)/$delta)*$delta;
                        $colors['green'] = intval((($colors['green'])+$half_delta)/$delta)*$delta;
                        $colors['blue'] = intval((($colors['blue'])+$half_delta)/$delta)*$delta;
                        if ($colors['red'] >= 256)
                        {
                            $colors['red'] = 255;
                        }
                        if ($colors['green'] >= 256)
                        {
                            $colors['green'] = 255;
                        }
                        if ($colors['blue'] >= 256)
                        {
                            $colors['blue'] = 255;
                        }

                    }

                    $hex = substr("0".dechex($colors['red']),-2).substr("0".dechex($colors['green']),-2).substr("0".dechex($colors['blue']),-2);

                    if ( ! isset( $hexarray[$hex] ) )
                    {
                        $hexarray[$hex] = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $hexarray[$hex]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Reduce gradient colors
            if ( $reduce_gradients )
            {
                // if you want to *eliminate* gradient variations use:
                // ksort( $hexarray );
                arsort( $hexarray, SORT_NUMERIC );

                $gradients = array();
                foreach ($hexarray as $hex => $num)
                {
                    if ( ! isset($gradients[$hex]) )
                    {
                        $new_hex = $this->_find_adjacent( $hex, $gradients, $delta );
                        $gradients[$hex] = $new_hex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $new_hex = $gradients[$hex];
                    }

                    if ($hex != $new_hex)
                    {
                        $hexarray[$hex] = 0;
                        $hexarray[$new_hex] += $num;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Reduce brightness variations
            if ( $reduce_brightness )
            {
                // if you want to *eliminate* brightness variations use:
                // ksort( $hexarray );
                arsort( $hexarray, SORT_NUMERIC );

                $brightness = array();
                foreach ($hexarray as $hex => $num)
                {
                    if ( ! isset($brightness[$hex]) )
                    {
                        $new_hex = $this->_normalize( $hex, $brightness, $delta );
                        $brightness[$hex] = $new_hex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $new_hex = $brightness[$hex];
                    }

                    if ($hex != $new_hex)
                    {
                        $hexarray[$hex] = 0;
                        $hexarray[$new_hex] += $num;
                    }
                }
            }

            arsort( $hexarray, SORT_NUMERIC );

            // convert counts to percentages
            foreach ($hexarray as $key => $value)
            {
                $hexarray[$key] = (float)$value / $total_pixel_count;
            }

            if ( $count > 0 )
            {
                // only works in PHP5
                // return array_slice( $hexarray, 0, $count, true );

                $arr = array();
                foreach ($hexarray as $key => $value)
                {
                    if ($count == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    $count--;
                    $arr[$key] = $value;
                }
                return $arr;
            }
            else
            {
                return $hexarray;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->error = "Image ".$img." does not exist or is unreadable";
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _normalize( $hex, $hexarray, $delta )
    {
        $lowest = 255;
        $highest = 0;
        $colors['red'] = hexdec( substr( $hex, 0, 2 ) );
        $colors['green']  = hexdec( substr( $hex, 2, 2 ) );
        $colors['blue'] = hexdec( substr( $hex, 4, 2 ) );

        if ($colors['red'] < $lowest)
        {
            $lowest = $colors['red'];
        }
        if ($colors['green'] < $lowest )
        {
            $lowest = $colors['green'];
        }
        if ($colors['blue'] < $lowest )
        {
            $lowest = $colors['blue'];
        }

        if ($colors['red'] > $highest)
        {
            $highest = $colors['red'];
        }
        if ($colors['green'] > $highest )
        {
            $highest = $colors['green'];
        }
        if ($colors['blue'] > $highest )
        {
            $highest = $colors['blue'];
        }

        // Do not normalize white, black, or shades of grey unless low delta
        if ( $lowest == $highest )
        {
            if ($delta <= 32)
            {
                if ( $lowest == 0 || $highest >= (255 - $delta) )
                {
                    return $hex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return $hex;
            }
        }

        for (; $highest < 256; $lowest += $delta, $highest += $delta)
        {
            $new_hex = substr("0".dechex($colors['red'] - $lowest),-2).substr("0".dechex($colors['green'] - $lowest),-2).substr("0".dechex($colors['blue'] - $lowest),-2);

            if ( isset( $hexarray[$new_hex] ) )
            {
                // same color, different brightness - use it instead
                return $new_hex;
            }
        }

        return $hex;
    }

    function _find_adjacent( $hex, $gradients, $delta )
    {
        $red = hexdec( substr( $hex, 0, 2 ) );
        $green  = hexdec( substr( $hex, 2, 2 ) );
        $blue = hexdec( substr( $hex, 4, 2 ) );

        if ($red > $delta)
        {
            $new_hex = substr("0".dechex($red - $delta),-2).substr("0".dechex($green),-2).substr("0".dechex($blue),-2);
            if ( isset($gradients[$new_hex]) )
            {
                return $gradients[$new_hex];
            }
        }
        if ($green > $delta)
        {
            $new_hex = substr("0".dechex($red),-2).substr("0".dechex($green - $delta),-2).substr("0".dechex($blue),-2);
            if ( isset($gradients[$new_hex]) )
            {
                return $gradients[$new_hex];
            }
        }
        if ($blue > $delta)
        {
            $new_hex = substr("0".dechex($red),-2).substr("0".dechex($green),-2).substr("0".dechex($blue - $delta),-2);
            if ( isset($gradients[$new_hex]) )
            {
                return $gradients[$new_hex];
            }
        }

        if ($red < (255 - $delta))
        {
            $new_hex = substr("0".dechex($red + $delta),-2).substr("0".dechex($green),-2).substr("0".dechex($blue),-2);
            if ( isset($gradients[$new_hex]) )
            {
                return $gradients[$new_hex];
            }
        }
        if ($green < (255 - $delta))
        {
            $new_hex = substr("0".dechex($red),-2).substr("0".dechex($green + $delta),-2).substr("0".dechex($blue),-2);
            if ( isset($gradients[$new_hex]) )
            {
                return $gradients[$new_hex];
            }
        }
        if ($blue < (255 - $delta))
        {
            $new_hex = substr("0".dechex($red),-2).substr("0".dechex($green),-2).substr("0".dechex($blue + $delta),-2);
            if ( isset($gradients[$new_hex]) )
            {
                return $gradients[$new_hex];
            }
        }

        return $hex;
    }
}
```

// loading library from within view

```
$this->load->library('GetMostCommonColors');
$ex = new GetMostCommonColors();
$colors=$ex->Get_Color($artwork->large_image, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put The file into library folder and load the the library using this code

```
$this->load->library('GetMostCommonColors');
```

This link will help you..

[Library detail documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: Thanks this doesn't seem to return anything, I've added the code i'm using to call the functions in the question…

Comment: Make sure you adjust your code to fit the library examples shown in the article. Such as making your functions public and so on `$this->GetMostCommonColors ->Get_Color ($artwork->large_image, 5)`

Comment: Library name need to be `ucfirst()` Get_most_common_collors (file too Get_most_common_collors.php) and also should be loaded with strtolower case i.e. `$this->load->library('get_most_common_collors')`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems the path is not correct, try the following code:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/assets/color.php');
```

or

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/assets/color.php';
```

but

```
include('/assets/color.php');
```

will work as well provided the assets folder is a sub-folder of the folder where the main file is from where you are making this inclusion.